# How to post an image on an user's wall directly from disk using the facebook graph api?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

On the [Facebook Graph API Post](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/) documentation the only way of posting images to a wall (user's or page's) is by providing the **picture** field on the request.

So I could use that and upload the image from my hard-disk to a server and use that url. Like this:

```
curl --form picture=http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/174s/66037848/Foals+png.png --form access_token=AAADChj --form message=msg1 https://graph.facebook.com/242001885843121/feed
```

But when I do that the **type** field of the post gets set as "status" and not as "photo".

I tried some different things like using the same request parameters used for uploading an image to an album with no success:

```
curl --form picture=@/tmp/fb_gallery.png --form access_token=AAADChj --form message=msg2 https://graph.facebook.com/242001885843121/feed

curl --form source=@/tmp/fb_gallery.png --form access_token=AAADChj --form message=msg2 https://graph.facebook.com/242001885843121/feed
```

I tried to set the type field to "photo" with no luck also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try out with this one it can upload 2 photos at a time

```
 curl 
 –F  'access_token=…' \
 -F  'batch=[{"method":"POST", \
              "relative_url":"me/photos", \
              "body":"message=My cat photo" \
              "attached_files":"file1" \
             },
             {"method":"POST", \
              "relative_url":"me/photos", \
              "body":"message=My dog photo" \
              "attached_files":"file2" \
             },
            ]'
 -F  'file1=@cat.gif' \
 -F 'file2=@dog.jpg' \
https://graph.facebook.com
```

Comment: Thanks Virendra. I never thought of "/me/photos" duh. Thanks!